# How to have a single instance of the activity when same activity is launched from any third party app

Tags: android

Suppose I have an activity "ACT1" which is launched in task "TASK1". But now I opened another app with task "TASK2" and launched same "ACT1". Now I have 2 instance of same activity in 2 different tasks. I want to have a single instance of that activity or that old task should have destroyed. How to achieve this?

I tried exploring different launch modes but it didn't helped.

Comment: Have you tried singleInstance or singleTask launch modes?  Also read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack on how tasks in Android work.  What you're trying to do is have a single Activity be in two tasks, which isn't normal (and may or may not be possible).  But you'd want the singleInstance/singleTask on the Activity you want shared between tasks.  Also, expect possible back button wonkiness

Comment: In google's api , singleInstance is the right way